# Tablayout tab with multiple fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am working on an app which use tab layout with 5 tabs. My need is to navigate multiple fragment inside every tab, and open the first fragment when user again reselected the tab. Please help me.

```
 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.scene_tab_selector));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.my_scene_tab_selector));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.conversation_tab_selector));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.notification_tab_selector));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.more_tab_selector));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdaptor adapter = new PagerAdaptor
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                if(tab.getPosition()==4)
                {
//                    pageTitleLabel.setText("My Profile");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


            }
        });
```

My PagerAdaptor is as follows

```
public class PagerAdaptor extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;


    public PagerAdaptor(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1ContainerFragment tab1 = new Tab1ContainerFragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                MyCuddllFragment tab2 = new MyCuddllFragment();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
//                CuddllConversationFragment tab3 = new CuddllConversationFragment();
                ConversationFragment conversationFragment = new ConversationFragment();
                return conversationFragment;

            case 3:
//                CuddllNotificationsFragment tab4 = new CuddllNotificationsFragment();
                Tab4ContainerFragment notificationPageFragment = new Tab4ContainerFragment();
                return notificationPageFragment;

            case 4:
                MyProfileFragment tab5 = new MyProfileFragment();
                return tab5;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }



}
```

Comment: Please can you tell what have you tried so far? Also can you mention issues you are facing in implementing as stated above

Comment: I tried view pager and pager adaptor. and in every tab first fragment is loaded. but now problem is traversing fragment in every tab

Comment: Share the code and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Please see my edited post

Comment: If I am not wrong then you need another viewpager inside Tab1ContainerFragment and adapter for that. But this time you need to manage the Fragments as children of Tab1ContainerFragment so you need ChildFragmentManager. I would suggest If you have not implemented it, then please implement it with 2 child fragments first.

Comment: can you please share any link or code

Comment: Every tabs have multiple page. like in tab1 there is recyler view when i click on any item then it will open next page in same tab. and when i re select same tab then it should gone in first fragment.

Comment: Any one have idea

Comment: @VinayakMishra try the following code if that makes any sense.

Comment: @android_Muncher i have try the following code but i did not got success.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            if(tab.getPosition()==0)
            {
               viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }else if(tab.getPosition()==1)
            {
              viewpager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }else if(tab.getPosition()==2)
            {
              viewpager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }else if(tab.getPosition()==3)
            {
              viewpager.setCurrentItem(3);
            }


        }
```

Comment: It does not help me to reach on first page of tab.

Comment: can we contact on facebook

Comment: @VinayakMishra I have made an edit. Try now. Sorry I was too tired when I wrote that.

Comment: Basically you just need to make sure that your fragments have a number attached to them. So that you know which fragment to display when a tab is clicked.

Comment: when can you avilable. i need to some discussion on it.

Comment: hmm..maybe share your code on github and I can fix it for you?